# love synchronism

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the one word that describes a couple or two people who might call or text at the same time because they are in sync with each other. Others would call it a coincidence but there is a word for lovers who are in sync. For some reason the word escapes me but there is one word for this.

Comment: Please include a sample sentence for how the word would be used.

Comment: What if the two "synchronized" people are just good friends or even more casually acquainted? Or even two people who don't like each other, and each post hostile tweets about the other one at the same time?

Comment: The word I am looking for would not describe people who don't like each other or just casually acquainted. It would be for 2 people who call or text each other at same time because they care for each other

Comment: Sample sentence: "Our feelings for each other are so "blank" we now text each other at same time in the morning.

Comment: "On the same wavelength"?

Comment: Dan Bron, you're close but not the word I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: You can continue Dan Bron's Physics terminology with *entangled*, or switch to Chemistry with *bonded*.

Comment: How about "like-minded"? or "in tune [with each other]"?

Answer (score 1):

simpatico
adjective  sim·pa·ti·co

Definition of simpatico
1
:  agreeable, likable
2
:  being on the same wavelength :

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that and I used to simply call it **telepathy** or that **"we are telepathic"**.

**Telepathy** (from the Ancient Greek τῆλε, tele meaning "distant" and πάθος, pathos or -patheia meaning "feeling, perception, passion, affliction, experience") is the purported transmission of information from one person to another without using any of our known sensory channels or physical interaction.

It is not for lovers I agree, however it does imply intensity of feeling from the definition.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Simpatico was the word I was looking for!